# Why does SSHTools SSH/SFTP server use another port to listen to server commands?

Tags: ssh, sftp

SFTP usually listens on port 22. But then I found an SFTP tool (SSHTools) that uses a command port to listen "for server commands such as stop". Why not make the server listen for the stop command on port 22 also?

Could this serve the same purpose as FileZilla's administration port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's for administration.

There's `SshDaemon` class/tool that uses the port to send "stop" command to the server via that port. Use `-stop` switch.

No other commands are supported.

Also note that the server listens on the command port on a loopback (localhost) interface only. So you cannot use it over Internet.